# cannot find module 'next/react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

ive recently started using next.js but after i make a project with npx create-next-app i face this error but i still can run the app

```
{
    "resource": "/E:/codes/news-website/news-website/pages/index.js",
    "owner": "eslint",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Parsing error: Cannot find module 'next/babel'\nRequire stack:\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\babel\\bundle.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\babel\\eslint-parser.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\eslint-config-next\\parser.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\@eslint\\eslintrc\\lib\\config-array-factory.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\@eslint\\eslintrc\\lib\\index.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\eslint\\lib\\cli-engine\\cli-engine.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\eslint\\lib\\cli-engine\\index.js\n- E:\\codes\\news-website\\news-website\\node_modules\\eslint\\lib\\api.js\n- c:\\Users\\Pasaria\\.vscode\\extensions\\dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.23\\server\\out\\eslintServer.js",
    "source": "eslint",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the EsLint extension if it is disabled in your code editors (vsCode), try to uninstall it as it may conflict with Eslint version installed with creat-next-app.